# is this the correct way to post xml as a string?

Tags: php, xml

I am supposed to send some xml to a web service as a string within an xml tag.  The sent file is showing up as "non-compliant", so I just want to check and make sure I am sending it correctly so I know if the error is from how it is being sent as opposed to the actual contents of the xml.  I am using PHP, so I create a string with the xml I want to send,

```
$send_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
             <myFile><stuff></stuff></myFile>';
```

I've placed it between the content tags in the outer xml like this:

```
<content><![CDATA["'.$send_xml.'"]]></content>
```

Shouldn't this send my "$send_xml" as a string?

Comment: yes, the sent file I referred to that shows up as "non-compliant" was the result.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider to not use the CDATA block as the CDATA block will break if `$send_xml` itself contains a CDATA block.

You might instead want to consider escaping the `$send_xml` string before putting it into an xml string.

PHP can do such escaping with the `htmlentities` function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have too many quotes.

Try:

```
<content><![CDATA['.$send_xml.']]></content>
```

...instead.

(Assuming your PHP string is single-quoted) your code will produce:

```
<content><![CDATA["<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myFile><stuff></stuff></myFile>"]]></content>
```

...where it should probably just be:

```
<content><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myFile><stuff></stuff></myFile>]]></content>
```

...without the inner XML being wrapped in double quotes.

Alternatively, this:

```
<content>'.htmlspecialchars($send_xml, ENT_COMPAT).'</content>
```

...should produce the same result at parse time, by escaping the special characters in the inner XML.

Comment: I had the same thought, and I did try it without the double quotes, didn't seem to make a difference.  I think you are right though, I will probably get rid of them.

Comment: I definitely think you should investigate the escaping route over CDATA, as @bardiir points out (and I ashamedly didn't notice) it would break if the inner XML contained a CDATA section. You say `The sent file is showing up as "non-compliant"` - is that by the remote server or by an XML validator?

Comment: The non-compliant status is just what I see listed on their "portal" web page for my account.  I'm not sure how that is determined, I just know it's what I want :)